# keep calculation result in xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a specific calculator and i want to keep calculation result in xml according to date of calculation.I have been research for 2 days but I could not find exactly what i want. When Save Button is clicked, calculator should save the initial variables and result in to xml by dynamically generated new attribute and child element like this: 
date will be date of calculation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kayıt>
    <date tarih="12.05.1989">
        <FRAME>3</FRAME>
        <TA>1</TA>
        <RESULTPDB>1,2</RESULTPDB>
        <RESULTPKW>500</RESULTPKW>
    </date>
    <date tarih="26.05.1989">
        <FRAME>3</FRAME>
        <TA>1</TA>
        <RESULTPDB>1,2</RESULTPDB>
        <RESULTPKW>500</RESULTPKW>
    </date>  
</kayıt>
```

Comment: This is just xml sample. Where is your C# code? Without code it's not clear what problem you have

Comment: actually I confused a little. I see there are many way to write xml but it could not work any of them. so I don't have code about writing xml.

Comment: XML file is just a text file. There is no need to use some special techniques in such simple scenario I guess...

Comment: It does not get simpler than Linq To Xml, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb387089.aspx

Comment: So what is the problem? Why _can't_ you produce this `xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have some objects like

```
public class Foo
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Frame { get; set; }
    public string TA { get; set; }
    public string PDB { get; set; }
    public string PKW { get; set; }
}
```

Saving list of these objects to XML with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb387089.aspx) (I strongly recommend you to read linked article):

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("kayit",
    from foo in foos
    select new XElement("date",
        new XAttribute("tarih", foo.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")),
        new XElement("FRAME", foo.Frame),
        new XElement("RESULTPDB", foo.PDB),
        new XElement("RESULTPKW", foo.PKW)
        )));

xdoc.Save("kayit.xml");
```

UPDATE: by list of foo objects I mean your entities which carry data for saving to xml. E.g.

```
var foos = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo { 
   Date = DateTime.Now, 
   Frame = comboBox1.Text,
   TA = label7.Text, 
   PDB = label13.Text, 
   PKW = label16.Text
    };
```

Comment: Im sorry i am new at this.  I try but it doesn't work. I can't catch foos. Could you please explain "foos"? by the way i write something else. it changes  changing date of xml file but when I open the xml file, its empty.

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
               
                string dosyayolu = Application.StartupPath + "\\XMLFile1.xml";
                doc.Load(dosyayolu);
              
                XElement contacts =
    new XElement("Contacts",
        new XElement("Contact",
            new XElement("asdasdasd", label2.Text),
            new XElement("Phone", "206-555-0144")
        )
    );doc.Save(dosyayolu);

Comment: @Ali see my update - I've added sample of `foos` list

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Its really nice to see helpful people. I 've Just left the office.  Tomorrow I Will take a look first place.

Comment: i changed it. it worked but when you save another result,instead of adding  the new result; it overwrite the previous result. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Ali you should read xml file (to `XDocument`), get existing element (e.g. root or `kayit`) and then add new element to content of existing element. Last step - save file again